# How return a Future<List<PokemonModel>> to use data in widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

My PokemonModel and Results class, i wan't return a List

```
 class PokemonModel {
  int count;
  String next;
  String previous;
  List<Results> results;

  PokemonModel({this.count, this.next, this.previous, this.results});

  PokemonModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    count = json['count'];
    next = json['next'];
    previous = json['previous'];
    if (json['results'] != null) {
      results = [];
      json['results'].forEach((v) {
        results.add(new Results.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['count'] = this.count;
    data['next'] = this.next;
    data['previous'] = this.previous;
    if (this.results != null) {
      data['results'] = this.results.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Results {
  String name;
  String url;

  Results({this.name, this.url});

  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    url = json['url'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I try use this on repository, i'll need ['next'], ['previous'] and results data to use in widgets but i cannot convert the data to a list of PokemonModel.

That's my current repository where i try get data.

```
    class PokemonRepository implements IPokemonRepository {
  Dio _dio;
  final String url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/';

  PokemonRepository([Dio dio]) : _dio = dio ?? Dio();
  @override
  Future<List<PokemonModel>> getPokemons() async {
    final response = await _dio.get(url);
    final poke = PokemonModel.fromJson(response.data);
    //how parse and return a list of pokemonmodel?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do it.

```
// method 1 (declarative/functional programming)
final List<PokemonModel> myList = response
    .map<PokemonModel>((item) => PokemonModel.fromJson(item))
    .toList();
return myList;
```

or

```
// method 2 (imperative)
final myList2 = <PokemonModel>[];
for (final Map<String, dynamic> item in response) {
  myList2.add(PokemonModel.fromJson(item));
}
return myList2;
```

I've seen it done both ways. Both return the same result.